# Refreshing div element on parent page from forms page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a main page (parent page) with AJAX requests. The page has a button to add new record on database - this will open a pop-up window (child page) with form. The form is submitted as POST onto another PHP file (Action.php) which will process the user input and create mysql query. Once successful, it closes the window.

Main page function to show information on DIV bottomButtons2:

```
function showJobs(str)
{
    if (str == "") 
    {
        document.getElementById("bottomButtons2").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onload = function() 
    {
        document.getElementById("bottomButtons2").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", "getInfo.php?f=3&q="+str);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Snippet from Action.php if the processing is successful:

`echo "<script> window.close(); </script>";`

I wanted to refresh the information in the bottomButtons2 div from parent page once successfully added a record to database. Is there a way to do this? I cannot use `window.opener.location.reload();` as it will refresh the whole page and losing the previously loaded information.

Comment: "I wanted to refresh the information" - why not use AJAX for this?

Comment: `this will open a pop-up window (child page) with form`...why? Just use a modal div, then everything will be on the same page to begin with.

Comment: @NicoHaase, i would of go with this option, but i don't know what and where to put the AJAX as I have 2 PHP files away from parent page.